# Correct scale of printed pdf Simulink models

Tags: matlab, pdf, export, simulink

Hi I'm trying to print some simulinks models to use them on a latex document.

I've checked the documentation and the posts in stackoverflow and found some answers but they didn't solve my problem.

I want to create a script to print several models with their correct scaling, so I used the commands:

```
set_param('model','PaperPositionMode','tiled')
set_param('model','ShowPageBoundaries','on')
set_param('model','PaperType','A4')
set_param('model','TiledPageScale','2')
print -dpdf -r300 -smodel model.pdf
```

When I change the TiledPageScale value I see the change in Simulink, but when I print the file either on pdf or eps the result is cropped the same as with TiledPageScale 1, no matter what value I've set.

I've checked the answer [Save Matlab Simulink Model as PDF with tight bounding box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21238591/save-matlab-simulink-model-as-pdf-with-tight-bounding-box) but I'm using matlab 2014a so I don't know if it's fixed yet

Thanks

EDIT: I'd ask or comment in the above post but I don't have the enough reputation